# What happen's to $\epsilon_1(x), \epsilon_2(x)?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given. If $f''$ exists, prove that $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2} = f''(x).$$ Find an example that this limit can exist even when $f''(x)$ fails to exist.

---

### At the end of the proof, how do I get rid of $\epsilon_1(x), \epsilon_2(x)?$

It follows from the Taylor formula that

\begin{align*}
f(x+h) &= f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + h^2\epsilon_1(x) \\
f(x-h) &= f(x) - hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + h^2\epsilon_2(x)
\end{align*}
So, $$\frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}$$ becomes $$ \frac{f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + h^2\epsilon_1(x) - 2f(x) + f(x) - hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + h^2\epsilon_2(x)}{h^2}$$ which, simplified, is $$h^2f''(x) + h^2(\epsilon_1(x) + \epsilon_2(x)).$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x-h)-2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2} = \\ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h^2f''(x) + h^2(\epsilon_1(x) + \epsilon_2(x))}{h^2} = \\ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f''(x) + \epsilon_1(x) + \epsilon_2(x) = \\ f''(x) + \epsilon_1(x) + \epsilon_2(x).$$

Comment: As an alternative you may apply L'Hopital Rule once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression of the error term in the 2nd order Taylor Theorem is incorrect.

First, the correct expression is that $\epsilon_1$ is a function of $h$ as well as $x$, and similarly for $\epsilon_2$. So wherever you have $\epsilon_1(x)$ and $\epsilon_2(x)$ you should instead have $\epsilon_1(x,h)$ and $\epsilon_2(x,h)$ (although sometimes the dependence on $x$ is suppressed when $x$ is regarded as a fixed value, hence the earlier version of my answer with $\epsilon_1(h)$ and $\epsilon_2(h)$).

Second, the limit behavior of the error term is important: when $x$ is fixed, the error approaches zero as $h \to 0$. So when $x$ is fixed we have
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \epsilon_1(x,h) = \lim_{h \to 0} \epsilon_2(x,h) = 0
$$

And now you should see that after you take the limit as $h \to 0$, all that's left is $f''(x)$.

Comment: I see. I just looked in my textbook and found that. Thank you, Lee.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is also a function of $x$ !

Comment: IT still tends to $0$ has $0$ tends to $0,$ right?

Comment: Fair enough, $\epsilon$ is a function of $x$ and $h$, I will put that into my answer. But the important thing is that when $x$ is fixed, $\epsilon$ limits to zero as $h$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about the Taylor expansion you may use L'Hospital rule and get your result.

$$ \lim _{h→0} \frac {f(x−h)−2f(x)+f(x+h)}{h^2}$$

$$ = \lim _{h→0} \frac {f'(x−h)+f'(x+h)}{2h}$$

$$ =\lim _{h→0} \frac  {f''(x−h)+f''(x+h)}{2} = f''(x)   $$

We are assuming that the second derivative is continuous.

Comment: What happen to "2f(x)" in the second line?

Comment: Also, thank you for the alternative answer. I wish I could check your answer as well!

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The $2f(x)$ disappears because we are taking derivative with respect  to $h$

Comment: Yes, that should have been obvious to me, given that the denominator changed from $h^2$ to $2h.$ Thanks, Mohammad! :)

Comment: Very good. Thanks,